# How to get a node value by referencing a node on its level that has no value

Tags: xslt

Using below xml example I need to get `<Child1>` with the value of 173
but I need to use the node `<Child>` to reference it. On my below example
`<Child>` doesn't exist on the node `<Child1>` that has a value of 173.

```
<GrandParent>
    <Parent>
        <Child>172</Child>
        <Sibling>15</Sibling>
        <Child1>172</Child1>
        <Sibling1>172_sibling</Sibling1>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <Child>171</Child>
        <Sibling>2</Sibling>
        <Child1>171</Child1>
        <Sibling1>171_sibling</Sibling1>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>        
        <Child1>173</Child1>
        <Sibling1>173_sibling</Sibling1>
    </Parent>
</GrandParent>
```

I tried using below code but it only returns null value. Thanks in advance.

```
<xsl:value-of select="otxsl:var-put('Child1_Value', Parent[Child='']/Child1)"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Parent[not(Child)]/Child1
```